# How to convert to a double in c#

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and am trying to make an app that allows to me to find the area of a circle, the user is to enter the radius of said circle and my app will our put the area, i am new to the Convert.ToDouble idea so i'm not sure how to get it to work. I keep getting an error saying:
'int' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.
I am trying to read the users input and save it as a double so i can use it in the equation, i didn't originally have the Convert.ToDouble in there but the error was saying it couldn't convert the int to double so i did some googling but i am still confused how it works as i've never used it before.
I have tried changing the 'int32' to things like String and Double but i keep getting the same error that it is not valid in the given context. Any help is appreciated :)

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter an radius");

        Radius = Console.ReadLine(Convert.ToDouble(Int32));

        Area = Pi * (Radius * Radius);

        Console.WriteLine("Your area is" + Area);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: We don't do pictures of code around here.  Better edit your question and enter the code as text.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste a code as text.

Comment: Sorry, i have never used this website either! lmao. Should be updated now

Comment: `Convert.ToDouble(Int32)` - can you explain what you think this is doing? Do you have a variable called `@Int32`? And have you checked the [samples for `Convert.ToDouble`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todouble?view=netcore-3.1#System_Convert_ToDouble_System_String_)?

Comment: Should be : Radius = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

Comment: @John I have no idea to be honest, i just had Radius = Console.ReadLine(); so that it could read the number that user entered. But i got an error message saying: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'double'

Comment: @jdweng that got it working. thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When converting an unknown string to a `double`, the best bet is the [`double.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1#System_Double_TryParse_System_String_System_Double__) method, because it does two things:

1. Returns a `bool` indicating whether or not the input was successfully parsed to a `double`
2. Sets an `out` parameter to the parsed value, or `0` if unsuccessful.

This is better than `Convert.ToDouble` because that method will just throw an exception if it fails.

Here's a good way to get a `double` from the user in a Console application, where we use the result of `double.TryParse` as a `while` condition, and we loop while it's not `true` (basically we wait for the user to enter a valid number before doing any calculations):

```
Console.Write("Please enter a radius: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();

double radius;

while (!double.TryParse(input, out radius))
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine($"{input} is not a valid number. Please try again.\n");
    Console.ResetColor();

    Console.Write("Please enter a radius: ");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}

double area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);

Console.WriteLine($"The area of a circle with radius {radius} is: {area}");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter an radius:");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if( double.TryParse(input, out double radius))
    {
       area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);   
       Console.WriteLine("Your area is" + Area);
    } else {
       Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input.");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```